# How to make button appear in center using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and jquery, and working on a small project for my school. I am using bootstrap in my application so that it can be responsive. The problem as you can see in [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY2TE.png) is that both buttons appear vertically at the top of their respective columns.How could I arrange both buttons so that they appear in middle of their respective columns.
Below is my code

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <section class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="project-name">Enter Data:</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textarea1"
      name="input1"></textarea>
     <div class="error" id="javaerror"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section class="col-sm-2 text-center">
    <div class="vcenter">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="data1">Process1</button>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section class="col-sm-5">
    <div>
     <label for="project-name">Result</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="result1"
      name="resultdata"></textarea>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
   <section class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="project-name">Enter Data:</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="textarea2"
      name="input2"></textarea>
     <div class="error" id="openerror"></div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section class="col-sm-2 text-center">
    <div class="vcenter">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="data2">Process2
      </button>
    </div>
   </section>
   <section class="col-sm-5">
    <div>
     <label for="project-name">Result</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="result2"
      name="resultDataNew"></textarea>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
 </div>
```

My requirements is that both button(Process1,Process2) should appear in the middle as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b20zI.png)

Comment: Have you tried `margin: auto 0;` in the stlying of the buttons?

Comment: I just tried, still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootsraps' 4 vertical alignment https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items

Comment: adding 'display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;' and adding this class at row level fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing,

You can insert a `<style>` before `<body>` which should be

```
    button.center{
    height:20px; 
    width:100px; 
    margin: -20px -50px; 
    position:relative;
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
}
```

Then for inserting any buttons in a centre you should write `<button type="button" class="center">Button</button>` and for inserting a normal button remove the center class.